# View Markup in Context menu? - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

While working in the code behind file, there's a need for me to jump to the HTML Markup. Is there a way to add this to the Context menu?

[image]

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question because I'm not satisfied with "no, it doesn't exist." An answer that shows how to accomplish this will win the bounty.

Comment: The bounty generated no answers :(

Comment: I looked around and I don't think this is possible. That's why I had accepted your earlier answer :)

Comment: I was hoping there might have been a 3rd party plug-in at the very least. Oh well, misery loves company at least.

Comment: 3 years later, a new IDE, and I'm still waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

I was able to add the "View Markup" menu item, but the menu item was disabled by Visual Studio.